# Share element transition between recyclerview item inside viewpager fragment to viewpager fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, transition

I have two activities `MainAcitity` and `DetailActivity`. `MainActivity` is containing `recyclerview` inside the fragment of `viewpager`. When I click on item it will go to `DetailActivity` and show the detail info inside the fragment of `viewpager` in `DetailAcitivty`.

**The Problems is:**

1. I want to add `transition` when I click on `recyclerview` item in `MainActivity` and go to `DetailActivity`.
2. When I back from the `DetailActivity` to `MainActivity` I want its transition will come to the item that I swiped in `viewpager`.

How can I achieve this?

**Note:**

-`MainAcitivty` and `DetailAcitivty` both are containing `viewpager`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to tag both your views with a unique transitionName.

```
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(imageView, "some_unique_transitionName");
```

start the new activity with this new information

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, imageView, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(imageView));

activity.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Now, on the new activity :
Depending on how you open your next activity and how complex is it's view hierarchy you'll  *might* want to leverage `supportPostponeEnterTransition();` during onCreate and `supportStartPostponedEnterTransition();`sometime later when it's set up. I'll let you read the documentation for it

Apart from that find the view on the new activity that needs to be animated and set the transition name on it

```
activityImage.setTransitionName(transitionName);
```

and let it rip.

few other things you might want to tinker with could be animation duration, interpolators etc.

```
 getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition().setDuration(200);
    getWindow().getSharedElementReturnTransition().setDuration(200)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
```

And, entry / exit transitions for your activities (you will need this)

```
    Fade fade = new Fade();
    fade.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
    fade.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(fade);
    getWindow().setExitTransition(fade);
```

Remember, the shared element transitions traverses the whole view hierarchy to find out the source and target views and only after the target activity is completely laid the framework reverse transitions to give you the illusion you want to achieve so yea, if the view hierarchies are complex or the activities take time to set up etc (Network dependent), you might need to tinker around a little bit more.